# Echoing row name where posted ID, for pre-selected form value

Tags: php, mysql, post, forms

This will hopefully be an easy one, but I'm lacking the skills!

```
                                <select name="search_category"  id="select1" >
<option value="">By Category</option>
 <?php if (!empty($_POST['search_category'])) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $_POST['search_category']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $_POST['search_category']; ?></option>
<?php }?>
  <?php foreach($categoriesListt as $row) : ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>

                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
```

The above is one of many select in a search module. It returns a dynamic list of options from a query higher up in my page. My goal is to have the option last searched pre-selected. Everything works as intended, but my problem is minimal really; the value of the posted search category is an ID($row->id. What I am hoping to do is use the associated $row->name for display, but keep the id for value so my search function still works.

In other words, I'm hoping to do something like:

```
<?php echo $row->name;  WHERE ID = $_POST['search_category']
```

Is there an easy way to do that in the above code, or will I need to add a special query at  the top of my page, fetching the individual row name that matches the posted id?

Thanks!

EDIT: To simplify, I already have a query that returns row->id and row->name, which I use in a foreach loop to populate my option values and names. I simply need a way, or a line that I can add to my query to also get the value of the row->name that matches the POSTED id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would write a short function which gives this functionality even for others applications.
just like

```
<?php 

    function($id, $table) {

        select ... etc

    }
?>
```

For security Reasons I would suggest to use Prepared Statements or mysql_escape

Hope i could help

Perhaps

```
SELCET('id', 'name' FROM yourTable WHERE 'name' = $_POST['ID'])
```

you mean something like this or would you select the dropdown option

```
<?php foreach($categoriesListt as $row) : ?> 
    <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"
          <?php if($row->name == $_POST['search_category']) : ?>
               selected="selected"<?php } ?>>
        <?php echo $row->name; ?>
    </option> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am absolutely not familiar with building or using functions, my skills are very limited. In any case, it won't be necessary for my other select options in the form as they all rely on actual keywords rather than an id.

Comment: OK, for me its normal to check all inputs to a Database even if i would use the system later on my own. But ok, you can establish a DB Connection in this function perhaps with mysqli (http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) to send a query like you typed.

Comment: Well I already have a query, it returns row->id and row->name, which populates my select options in the first place. My question is how do I then get the single row->name value that matches the posted ID?

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you thank you! It was the 2nd option, I just needed to add an if clause IN the loop, duh! THANK YOU!